# Does {{'any'}} have a watcher? Is {{::'any'}} a performance improvement?

Tags: angularjs

I am going to improve the perfomance of my angular app. So I decided to use {{::variable}} more often (>angular 1.3). For translations I used the writting {{'key.header'|translate}}. 
Is a performance improvement possible if i use {{:'key.header'|translate}} or does angular know that these strings won't change?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to indicate to angular that your string would not change is using `{{::variable}}`. And yes, it's a performance improvement because you are telling to angular to evaluate that expression once and then ignore it (avoiding two-way binding) and never watch it again. So,

`less watchers =  better performance`

NOTE:

You can set an angular expression using `::`, only if your expression wouldn't be changed over the time. In your case(about your comment), if you want to use that expression to get a translated version on a string, you should not use it then, because the user may changes the language any time and it needs got changed.

**Conclusion**

You should use `::` over angular expressions that wouldn't be changed over the time. `::` is a way to declare a *constant* and reduce your watchers, getting a better performance.

Comment: Nice, Thank you. 
Do you know if <span translate="any"> </span> also uses a watcher?

Comment: @ThomasZoé if "any" is an angular expression, it uses watcher unless you say otherwise.

Comment: I found following link: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/738

They think that you don't want this behavior.

Comment: @ThomasZoé yep, that right, I added a note in my answer, check it.